# Why is broadband so slow

Tags: networking, lenovo, download-speed, broadband

I have a new Lenovo laptop running ubuntu. My old Windows 7 laptop gives me download speeds up to 65 mbs download on my virgin wifi. My new Ubuntu laptop gives me 4 mbs download at best and 3.5 mbs upload. I tested it with a wired connection, to little improvement. Will re-test tomorrow with a new Cat6 ethernet cable. Here is the (I assume relevant) Lenovo configuration:

```
description: Notebook
product: 82C7 (LENOVO_MT_82C7_BU_idea_FM_V15-ADA)
vendor: LENOVO
version: Lenovo V15-ADA
serial: PF2K96CL
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.1.1 dmi-3.1.1 smp vsyscall32
core
description: Motherboard
product: LNVNB161216
vendor: LENOVO
physical id: 0
version: No DPK
serial: PF2K96CL
slot: Chassis Location Unknown
*-memory
description: System Memory
physical id: 1
slot: System board or motherboard
size: 8GiB
*-bank:0
description: Row of chips DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
product: 4ATF1G64HZ-3G2E1
vendor: Micron Technology
physical id: 0
serial: 29B4129C
slot: DIMM 0
size: 8GiB
width: 64 bits
clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
*-firmware
description: BIOS
vendor: LENOVO
physical id: c
version: E8CN25WW
date: 10/13/2020
size: 128KiB
capacity: 8MiB

*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 32
serial: **:**:**:**:**:**
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
```

Now I am not a techie and am an ubuntu newbie. Has anyone suggestions as to why it does not match 'old laptop' speeds (at same location, at same time). Even if the wired connection with upgraded cable (delivery tomorrow) surely the wifi speed should match that of old Windows 7 computer?

Comment: How are you testing your download speeds?

Comment: Can you try: Sitting right next to the router, using wifi on a not-so-buzy place with not a lot of other wifi networks

Comment: Braodband speeds checked using Broadbad Speedchecker - have also tried 2 or 3 other sites, similar results.

Comment: Tried speed right next to router, also withe cat6 ethernet connection. Speed no better with wifi, with ethernet slightly faster up to 9 mbs but no where near approaching old laptop speeds of 65 mbs for wifi.

Comment: Speeds checked after a factory reset of router. The old laptop speeds were checked yesterday. Is this an Ubuntu config issue?

Comment: Well I have solved the problem. Nothing to do with router, cables, Virgin broadband, etc.. It was a Browser Issue. I changed to Opera and the download speeds were very much faster. Back to Firefox, the 'native' Ubuntu browser, and followed the links to speed up Firefox. ==> Help==>Troubleshoot Mode==> Restart Firefox in Troubleshoot Mode. This temporarily disables all add-ons. Broadband speed check now gave download speed of over 80mbs, considerable improvement over 3mbs previously. Sometimes the obvious solutions have the capacity to evade us (well me in particular!). Thanks for suggestions.